# Cannot build after npm start

Tags: node.js

I am brand new to node.js and I am trying to build my app so that I can deploy it.

Right after I do `npm start` I cannot do anything. Sorry if the question is too obvious, but I have never used node.js before.

[image]

Cmd says that I can build my app which is what I want but I cannot type anything.
I have tried doing `npm run build` before doing `npm start` but I get an empty index.html.

These are my `package.json`'s scripts:
[image]

Comment: Either open another terminal window or stop the app using CTRL+C then you can type `npm run build`

Comment: `npm start` does, what one would expect from a command callec `start`, it starts the backend of your app, which seems to be some server listening on port 3000. While this server is running, you obviously cannot input other commands into the console ( unless the app itself allows or expects some input) ...

Comment: I see, that does build my app but I am still getting an empty index.html. I do not see my app which shows up when I do npm start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `npm start` your app is running continuously. So if you want to type a new command, you would have to stop it or open a new terminal window/tab and run that command there. Just make sure you are in the same path you want to be.
In order to stop a running process (e.g. `npm start`) simply press `ctrl + c` (that is, `ctrl` first, keep it pressed and then press `c`) no matter if you are using mac or windows

Comment: Thank you, that does help. I thought that to not get an empty index.html I would need to do `npm start` and then `npm run build`. My app is still empty after I build it and I am not seeing my app which does show on localhost when I do `npm start`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: While using create-react-app, during development, after running npm start simply go to localhost:3000 and you should see the app. No need to touch the index.html file